# Ошибка TypeScript при экспорте компонента React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, export

При экспорте компонента React, TypeScript выводит ошибку

> TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

```
export connect(mapStateToProps)(AnimalForm);
```

Ошибка исчезает, только если добавить default, но мне он не нужен.

Comment: А что же тогда нужно? У вас написан невалидный JavaScript

Comment: @Alexey Ten что значит невалидный? Это Redux

Comment: export либо default, либо декларация переменной, константы или функции. У вас же ни один из этих вариантов. 
А как вы потом собираетесь импортировать этот компонент?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать внутренний псевдоним компонента до применения функции высшего порядка

```js
const AnimalFormInternal = () => { ... }

export const AnimalForm = connect(mapStateToProps)(AnimalFormInternal);
```